# SSR stop working after upgrade to Spartacus v3.0

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Since the upgrade to Spartacus v3.0 SSR stop working with this output:

```
Unknown http response error: -1
Unknown http response error: -1
SSR rendering exceeded timeout, fallbacking to CSR for /
```

This happens for every route on the first render and then it fallback to CSR.

I tried to raise the timeout to a higher value, but that didn't help:

server.ts

```
...

const ngExpressEngine = NgExpressEngineDecorator.get(engine, { timeout: 10000 });

...
```

I get the same behaviour when I create a new Angular app and add the Spartacus schematics. Any idea how I can debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Unknown http response error: -1` might indicate, that there is an issue with connection to backend server, did you check if everything works as intended?

If server indeed is missing proper ssl certificate, try adding

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

to server.ts (for debugging only!)

2. You can also disable the timeout and Spartacus built-in SSR optimizations completely with:

```
const ngExpressEngine = NgExpressEngineDecorator.get(engine, null);
```

3. You can also debug your SSR server, as explained in the docs (https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/how-to-debug-server-side-rendered-storefront/#nodejs-debugging-in-vs-code)

Comment: You are my hero :)
My test server has a self signed certificate and `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` fix my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After setting below to **package.json**, the SSR begin to work:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev:ssr": "cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 ng run mystore:serve-ssr",
},
[...]
"devDependencies": {
    [...]
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0"
}
```

You need run

```
yarn dev:ssr
```